# DOMXPath in PHP return empty strings

Tags: php, xpath

I am using xpath for web scraping. I can get expected results from some sites(Yahoo etc.) But I can not get the data at specific pages. I only get empty strings. What is my problem?

```
 $html = file_get_contents('http://finance.naver.com/item/frgn.nhn?code=005930');
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);  

 if(!empty($html)){ 

     @$doc->loadHTML($html);
     libxml_clear_errors(); 
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);        

     $row = $xpath->query('//span[@class="tah p10 gray03"]') ;      

     if($row->length > 0) {

            foreach($row as $v){

                $stock[] = $v->nodeValue  ; 

            }     

           var_dump($stock) ;

        } 
}
```

- url Contents: 2018.12.28
- expected results : 2018.12.28 , etc.
- actual results : array(20) {[0]=>string(0) ""[1]=>string(0) ""[2]=>string(0) ""[3]=>string(0) ""[4]=>string(0) ""[5]=>string(0) ""[6]=>string(0) ""[7]=>string(0) ""[8]=>string(0) ""[9]=>string(0) ""[10]=>string(0) ""[11]=>string(0) ""[12]=>string(0) ""[13]=>string(0) ""[14]=>string(0) ""[15]=>string(0) ""[16]=>string(0) ""[17]=>string(0) ""[18]=>string(0) ""[19]=>string(0) "" }

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193775/what-would-cause-domnodenodevalue-to-be-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but I found that it [may be a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193775/what-would-cause-domnodenodevalue-to-be-empty) - so you need to have your `$html` UTF-8 encoded.

I added the following line after your first line:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

It converts `$html` to UTF-8. After that I can see the results:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2018.12.28"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2018.12.27"
...
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. Now It works. (same url but different pages Setting of UTF-8)